# Mapping of $\mathbb{N}$ to a finite range $\mathbb{R}$ with uniform density

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

It is quite easy to bijectively map the whole of $\mathbb{N}$ to an arbitrary subrange in $\mathbb{R}$. For instance:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{(x+1)}$

neatly maps all the natural numbers into the range $[0\ldots1]$. However, the density of this mapping is not very uniform. For any $\epsilon$, I can always find only a finite number of $x$s that get mapped to a number greater than $\epsilon$. Casually speaking, most of the mapped numbers cluster near the $0$.

I can also trivially find a mapping that does not show this clustering, like $f(x) = x/2$, but now my target range is no longer finite.

It is my impression that this is always the case, that any mapping from $\mathbb{N}$ to a finite range in $\mathbb{R}$ will always have one or more cluster points, where most of the mapped numbers end up.

Is it possible to construct a bijective mapping that shows a uniform density of the mapped points - that is, no subrange of the target range will contain infinitely more points than another?
If not, what would be a convincing argument (preferably something that a high-schooler can understand) that this is not possible?

Comment: $f(n)= \cos n$ works (although it's not trivial).

Comment: @Crostul Oh yeah, I was looking for bijective mappings. I should add that to the question. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Actually $\cos n$ is injective on naturals. I mean that $\cos n = \cos m$ implies $n=m$ for two natural numbers.

Comment: @Crostul That's interesting, I didn't know that. But as you mentioned, proving this is probably not trivial.

Comment: There is no bijective mapping of $\Bbb N$ onto $(a,b)$, because $(a,b)$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequnce:$$0,1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac23,\frac14,\frac34,\frac15,\frac25,\frac35,\frac45,\frac16,\ldots$$It satisfies both conditions that you are interested in.

Comment: That's a really nice example. Could you provide the closed form for this sequence?

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think that such a closed form exists.

Comment: "satisfies both conditions"? One of the condiitions he asks for is that the map be a bijection...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich A bijaction to an arbitray subrange. My guess is that this means injective.

Answer (score 0):

An example that has some independent use is that if $\alpha$ is an irrational number, defining $f$ to be the fractional part of $n \alpha$ has the property you seek.